# setAnimationDidStopSelector: not getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, uiview

I know this question gets asked a lot but i have tried all the other answers and i can't figure out why the animation stop selector does not get called. Here is the code:

```
-(void) moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration curve:(int)curve  x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y annKey:(NSString *) annKey{  

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
image.transform = transform;
[UIView beginAnimations:annKey context:NULL];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

This is the main animation function that gets sent all the correct parameters.

```
- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
{
if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"Burn"])
{
    NSLog(@"Animation: %@ has finished.",animationID);
}

NSLog(@"This does not get called, why not?");
}
```

None of my NSLogs display text. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have two `beginAnimations`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, i have removed the first one from the code. But the problem still exists.

Comment: Move this line, `[UIView beginAnimations:annKey context:NULL];` to the top of the `moveImage:duration:curve:x:y:annKey:` method.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason you're not using the block-based UIView animations calls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need tho do -

```
[UIView beginAnimations:annKey context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];

// Now define rest.
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
image.transform = transform;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the problem is, but you really shouldn't be using beginAnimations/commitAnimations. Instead, use block animations. You define the completion code directly in the completion portion of the call.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // animation code
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // completion code
                 }];
```